# Can I hire non-licensed architecture firm for residential project?

Tags: remodeling, renovation, architecture

I recently considering on a major renovation/remolding of our house in Los Angeles, and we do contacted a few candidates from online, the talented one we like told us that their small firm is not a licensed architecture firm in California. And we are told in California an architecture license is not required to work on residential project. I'm not sure if this is true, and we really do want to hire them, but we don't want get into any troubles in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept.

Comment: If you like the plans and submit them to the county they may be approved. However if there are parts of the structure that require an engineering stamp the county will notify you you need engineering approved plans , I have done this , I designed a shop submitted plans , they wanted engineering prints , stamped , I found an engineer, that provided the addition detail the county wanted with his stamp. Plans approved and it was built. The only problem was we had to wait for the approval another 6? Weeks I don’t remember it’s been a couple of decades but it can be done , it may cost more time & $

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your answers, just add the the location--Los Angeles.

Comment: I'm also wondering, does the plan need to be stamped by the licensed architect before submit to the city, because we have the expansion involved. we want to add a room on our backyard connects with our house.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a licensed and/or registered architect for a residential project in California.

You can check with the State licensing agency. Here: https://www.cab.ca.gov/

The building department can require anything, including peanut butter on the roof. (If they do, there’s an appeals process, which they’d loose on the peanut butter issue.)

However, if they require seismic calculations, footing calculations, plumbing calculations, electrical calculations, setback requirements, etc. your designer can hire a local engineer and/or architect to prepare such calculations.

Make certain you know what your design firm is responsible for...approved plans and specs suitable for a building permit? AND what is the fee for such plans and specs and when they’ll be completed and suitable for submission to the Building Department.

Also, are they going to assist during construction? If not, what is their fee (hourly) to answer the contractor’s questions.

Are they helping pick the colors, size of HVAC unit(s), plumbing fixtures, vents, etc.

Comment: I just did a major remodeling project, no license architect, but all major structure changes, removing walls, and bearing walls mods, were calculated by license structural engineer.  The building inspector also informed us of what had to have calculations with stamps by license engineer before the drawings were accepted and a building permit was issued.  Calif-Bay area

Answer (score 0):

A lot of residential projects only have designers.

I don't know explicitly about California but I'd expect this varies with the individual cities/counties and if architects are required in certain places it would certainly not be a state wide requirement.

Comment: Los Angeles, to be specific. thank you

Answer (score 0):

California might not require it but there could be some legal problems down the road if someone gets hurt. I'd be checking with my homeowner's insurance company to make sure I'd still be covered with a non licensed architecture, and get it in writing.

Comment: The county reviews the plans if a portion of the plans are not “standard” the county redlines the plans and “fails” some sections until additional requirements are met (in my case a 11’ below grade retaining wall required a larger footer and more rebar plus a stamp 1k and resubmit) and they were approved same thing will happen with a company that draws up the plans because really that’s all they are doing because the state doesn’t recognize them as engineers, or that’s what I was told. The county approved the plans they meet code and that’s all that is needed. Same if your name is Mickey Mouse

Comment: If I may understood you correctly, you meant if the house is designed by a non-licensed architect, then the homeowner's insurance will be differently in the future?? so the difference would not be only about the process, it will also be a consequentially difference. This is serous. @JACK

Comment: @EricC  Not as serious as you make it sound. I'm just suggesting you verify with them, check your policy, to make sure you don't have to use licensed firms. My sister's a lawyer so I hear all this weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is really only going to be answered by your local inspector.   Tell him what you plan on doing and who will be doing the design.  Ask him if he has any problems.   Be up front.   There is a good chance the firm you are using could do everything and have an engineer stamp it which might be just a couple hundred more.